# Locking & deleting

Tags: support, deletion, deleted-questions, locked-posts

Recently, a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2659982/does-the-law-of-cosines-contradict-pythagorass-theorem) was deleted while locked. The [Help Center](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/locked-posts) says,

> In most cases, a post which is "locked" cannot be modified in any way. Locking prevents...
>
> ...voting on the post (including close/reopen votes for questions)
> ...editing
> ...commenting
> ...answering (for questions)
> ...flagging (though "in need of moderator intervention" flags are still allowed, except in the case of Historical Significance locks - see below)

Yet, it appears that several people were able to vote to delete, and able to delete this locked question.

Am I missing some loophole in the locking provisions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This restriction does not apply to moderators.

Non-moderator votes, if any, could have been cast before the lock. The lock does not nullify those.

Comment: OK. So, when it says, "deleted by users X, Y, Z, and moderator W", that's a little misleading; the votes of X, Y, and Z had no effect, and it was really deleted unilaterally by W. A little glitch in the software, just enough to confuse me.

Comment: The same remark would apply to every closure or every deletion in which a moderator participates. Technically the one vote would always have been sufficient.But the other users *still had recorded their opinion as well.*

Comment: There were in fact W, X, Y, Z users voting to delete (four of them), and one (who happened to be the fifth user) mod made five to delete.  Clean as clean can be, @Gerry.